# How to keep track of an unknown number of asynch web service requests

Tags: playframework

I have the following scenario I want to implement:

I follow a list of users, and each of those people follow a list of other users (think Twitter). I want to do the following:

- Given a particular user, get all the people that user follows
- From that list of `x` people, make `x` requests in parallel to get the list of people that they follow

In Play, I want to do this via the WS API, and I am guessing that when I make the `x` requests in parallel, I will have `x` Future objects representing the result of each of those calls. My question is, how can I determine when all the Futures are complete? I am ok with a few requests failing, as long as the majority return successfully. Once they are all returned I want to do some computation on the aggregate of all the responses.

How can I determine when all the Futures are complete, given that I don't know ahead of time how many `x` will be?

Answer (score 0):

You can compose your futures using flatMap, the exemple below sends multiple request using an array of urls the concatenate all results body:

```
def compser = Action.async {
        val urls = List("http://jmaghreb.io","http://google.com","http://yahoo.fr","http://moroccojug.org")
        val futures:List[Future[WSResponse]] = urls.map(u=> WS.url(u).get())

        var f = futures.foldLeft[Future[String]](Future[String]{""})((e,c)=>{
          e.flatMap(oldRes => c.map(x=>oldRes+" ==> "+x.body))
        })

        f.map(s => Ok(s)).recover({case f=> Ok(s"Failure $f")})
      }
```

This way you can concatenate all your futures results.

If you want to ignore failed request you can just add recover inside the flatMap as shown here:

```
var f = futures.foldLeft[Future[String]](Future[String]{""})((e,c)=>{
  e.flatMap(oldRes => {
    c.map(x=>oldRes+" ==> "+x.body).recover({case f=> oldRes })
  })
})
```