# How do I process this list of futures result

Tags: scala

I have the following function:

```
def countAllFriends(currUser: String, members: List[String]): Future[Map[String, Integer]] = {
    val results: List[Future[List[String]]] = members.map(currUser => retrieveAllFriends( currUser))


    //go through the results, and return a future of a map of usernames to the number of times that username exists in the list


  }
```

How can I implement the function so that I get a return type of `Future[Map[String, Integer]]` ?

If a future fails, then I don't want the whole thing to fail, I just want to have a special entry in the map called 'failures' which will count the number of failed futures.

Comment: it's pretty much the same answer I gave you on your previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302087/how-to-keep-track-of-an-unknown-number-of-asynch-web-service-requests/25306275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `Future.sequence` to get a `Future[List[List[String]]`:

```
val p: Future[List[List[String]]] = Future.sequence(results)
```

Then `flatMap` the future and the inner lists and use `groupBy` and `map`:

```
val g: Future[Map[String, Int]] = p.flatMap { listOfList =>
  Future(listOfList.flatten.groupBy(identity).map(maps => (maps._1, maps._2.length)))
}
```

Edit:

If you want to count the number of futures failed you could use this:

```
val futuresWithRecover: List[Future[List[String]]] = 
  results.map(f => f.map(identity).recover {case _ => List("failures") })
```

Then the process is the same:

```
val p: Future[List[List[String]]] = Future.sequence(futuresWithRecover)

val g: Future[Map[String, Int]] = p.flatMap { listOfList =>
  Future(listOfList.flatten.groupBy(identity).map(maps => (maps._1, maps._2.length)))
}
```

The second approach though is untested.